# How to retrieve total amount of an order to the database in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to retrieve the total amount of the selected items that
is being purchased by the user in the cart.
When the user check-outs, he is redirected to a Order page where the
user fills out all the information and submits the order .but the total amount is not getting reflected in the database.

forms.py (In my orders app)

```
  from django import forms
  from .models import Order


  class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address', 
        'postal_code', 'city']
```

models.py (In my Order App)

```
 from django.db import models
 from shop.models import Product


  class Order(models.Model):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      email = models.EmailField()
      address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      total_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,       
      decimal_places=3, default=0)


       class Meta:
           ordering = ('-created', )

       def __str__(self):
         return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)


       def total_cost(self):
          return sum([item.total_cost for item in self.items.all()])

       def get_total_cost(self):
          return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


   class OrderItem(models.Model):
       order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items',  
       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       product = models.ForeignKey(Product, 
       related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
        total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, 
        decimal_places=3, default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.id)

        def get_cost(self):
             return self.price * self.quantity
```

views.py (In my orders App)

```
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from .models import OrderItem
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
   from .forms import OrderCreateForm
   from cart.cart import Cart


   @login_required
   def order_create(request):
     cart = Cart(request)
     if request.method == 'POST':
       form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save()
        for item in cart:
            OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=order,
                product=item['product'],
                price=item['price'],
                quantity=item['quantity'],
                total_price=item['total_price'],
            )
        cart.clear()
        return render(request, 'created.html', {'order': order})
      else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

I have used crispy forms for rendering the form

create.html

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  {% load static %}
  {% block title %}
  Your Shopping Cart| Checkout
  {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 6%">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h4 class="page-header">Billing Details</h4>
            <form action="." method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form | crispy }}<br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"       
                value="Submit order">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="page-header">
                Your Order
                 <li class="list-group-item ">Total Cost: Rs {{ 
                  cart.get_total_price }}</li>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                {% for item in cart %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{ item.quantity }} x {{ item.product.name }}
                    <span>Rs. {{ item.total_price }}</span>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}


            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Cart.py (in my Cart app)

```
   from decimal import Decimal
   from django.conf import settings
   from shop.models import Product


  class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
    self.session = request.session
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart = cart

   def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price':   
         str(product.price)}
    if update_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
    self.save()

   def save(self):
     self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
    self.session.modified = True

  def remove(self, product):
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id in self.cart:
        del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

  def __iter__(self):
    product_ids = self.cart.keys()
    products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    for product in products:
        self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

    for item in self.cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
        item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
        yield item

 def __len__(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

 def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in 
    self.cart.values())

 def clear(self):
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    self.session.modified = True
```

admin.py(In my orders app)

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from .models import Order, OrderItem


  class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    raw_id_fields = ['product']


    class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',   
       'address', 'postal_code', 'city', 'total_cost', 'paid', 
       'created','updated']
        list_filter = ['paid', 'created', 'updated']
        inlines = [OrderItemInline]


 admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Outputs:-

These are the outputs of the template and in the database, where we can see there the amount of Total Price is 0.00

[create.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjPUu.png)

[database - ADMIN page - Orders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IhKi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying just the `total_price` from the `OrderItem`

You arent doing anything at all with the `total_price` of the `Order` object so that will remain 0

What I suggest you to do is to have a calculated total_price field for Order.

So instead:

```
  class Order(models.Model):
      total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,       
      decimal_places=3, default=0)
```

Something like:

```
  class Order(models.Model):
      def total_price(self):
          return sum([item.total_price for item in self.items.all()])
```

Keep in mind maybe you have to tweak a bit your Admin view to display the field although I think it wont be necessary,

Comment: Hello, I tried doing that... it still isn't getting updated. Just wanted to make one thing clear ->  my "total_price" of OrderItem class is getting updated. As in the output , it is been shown  Price of Rs.200 and Quantity of 5 is getting multiplied to getting the total_price in OrderItem as Rs.1000, also Price of Rs.200 and Quantity of 9 are getting multiplied to get the total_price in OrderItem as Rs.1800. What I wanted is to get the sum of this total_price in OrderItem that is 1800+1000 = 2800 to be displayed in the total_price of the Order class.

Comment: i did tweak as you said. But still the data is not getting reflected.

Comment: @KishoreShyam still not working? can I see your updated code?

Comment: IntegrityError at /orders/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_order.total_cost .. I get this error. i have changed total_price to total_cost

Comment: As you can see in the create.html output... the total Cost is shown.. But still the same isn't getting reflected in the database.

Comment: does the property `total_price` get stored with each Order ?

Comment: @AnuragDhadse that's a calculated field, is not stored, only calculated on demand.